# Locking copy operation of std::shared_ptr inside lambda

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, c++17

For this sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>

struct A
{
    int _i;
    A(int i):_i(i)
    {
        std::cout<<"A() "<<_i<<std::endl;
    }
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout<<"~A() "<<_i<<std::endl;
    }
    void Print()
    {
        std::cout<<"Print() "<<_i<<std::endl;
    }
};

struct B
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> Asp;
    std::mutex AspMutex;

    void SetA()
    {
        static int i = 0;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(AspMutex);
        Asp = std::make_shared<A>(i);
    }

    void AccessA1()
    {
        std::shared_ptr<A> aspCopy;
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(AspMutex);
            aspCopy = Asp;
        }
        (*aspCopy).Print();
    }

    void AccessA2()
    {
        auto aspCopy = [&]()
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(AspMutex);
            return Asp;
        }();
        (*aspCopy).Print();
    }

    void AccessA3()
    {
        (*[&]()
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(AspMutex);
            return Asp;
        }()
        ).Print();
    }

};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.SetA();
    std::thread t([&]{b.SetA();});
    b.AccessA1();
    b.AccessA2();
    b.AccessA3();
    t.join();
}
```

I'm curious if c++17 (or later) standard will guarantee that `A::Access1` and `A::Access2` methods are thread safe (copy of `std::shared_ptr` will be protected by `lock`).

Comment: Can you explain what isn't thread safe about it currently? Because it seems like you're accessing `Asp` behind the locks.

Comment: I don't get the question.  You lock, then copy.  Why wouldn't that be thread safe?

Comment: Edit : Never mind, I missed the `b.SetA()` before `std::thread`.

Comment: @NicolBolas to my knowledge nothing. I was just curious if it can be dangerous in any way. For ex. Lambda in `Access2` could do not copy `shared_ptr` but use original one etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The lock makes `A::Access1` and `A::Access2` thread safe with concurrent `SetA`. This is still true in C++17.